# Can 行う and 施行する be used interchangeably when meaning "to carry out?"

Tags: word-choice, nuances

I'd learned 行う as meaning "to carry out" a while back, and had understood it to mean something like carrying *an action* out, or *performing* an action. [The definition offered in Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%86) appears to corroborate this.

I recently learned 施行 as "carry out" too. [The definition in Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%96%BD%E8%A1%8C) appears to suggest it can be used in that meaning to denote the carrying out *of plans, policies, rules, etc.*

Can 行う also be used in the sense of carrying out a policy or a rule too? Can 施行する be used to mean carrying out anything other than policies or rules, like more general actions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can 施行する be used to mean carrying out anything other than policies or rules, like more general actions?

Practically no. Searching on [BCCWJ](https://clrd.ninjal.ac.jp/bccwj/), most 施行する are used in the sense of *putting (a law) into effect* or *carrying out (a policy)*. There are a few examples where it is used for medical treatment/therapy, as 放射線治療を施行する.

> Can 行う also be used in the sense of carrying out a policy or a rule too?

For laws/rules, no. X法を行う does not sound idiomatic. For policies, I suppose it is mostly ok. E.g., 経済政策を行う=carry out economic measures. Note that 行う is very generic and it may be more common to use verbs like 実施する which is more restrictive in terms of verb collocations.